# Can't use samsung tablet in class?

Tags: technology-in-education

I've been using my tablet for years teaching in a high school. Now I moved to another school teaching middle school. I spoke to the principal and he said there's no problem in using a tablet as long as it doesn't have a SIM card or any distracting apps (social networks, chatting, etc.). After the first week of school, they are telling me that "students don't accept this tablet in class" and they consider it "no different from a cellphone". I explained to them that all my books and courses are on it and it isn't easy to print all of them and that, after a little time, students won't notice it anymore. I also explained to the students that this tablet contains their course and exercises and that I only use it as a reader but that didn't help much.

So, is it normal to ban a tablet in school? If so, it seems I only have two choices: either print all the courses or stop working at this school. What should I do about it?

Comment: tab=tablet? And do all the students have a "tab" or are you projecting yours?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke yes it's a tablet. I don't have any projector in class. I use the tablet just to read from just as I use a paper. It's way more efficient, I don't have to constantly print and carry a lot of papers.

Comment: Do you have a way to motivate the tablet, by using it for fancy presentations for example?

Comment: @DirkLiebhold They don't have any projector in class.

Comment: Oh... Maybe you can get the school on a path towards more (modern) technology in the classroom (it might be quite a long road, though, if they don't even have projectors...).

Comment: The lunatics are running this asylum.

Comment: I do understand why the students can't use tablets, but I don't understand why _you_ can't use it.

Comment: @user26832 Me neither. It seems the students didn't find anything to criticize the new teacher (me) except that he's using a tablet and they are not used to this.

Comment: This is just bizarre. After reading the question, I thought, "I must not be understanding this correctly." But based on the comments, I guess I am, and you are either in a truly dysfunctional workplace or are dealing with a crazy person.

Comment: @BenCrowell If you've been in middle school lately, you would know that you invariably deal with a great number of crazy people - adolescents. A persecution complex is part of the normal disposition. Most (if not all) middle schools in my town ask staff not to 'get caught' using their cell phones, because of the inequality, or perceived inequality, inherent in students being required to store devices in their lockers during the day. For better or worse, the prevailing opinion is that it's too much for students at this age to understand that there can be different rules for staff and students.

Comment: Also note that students who do understand the rationale for differing rules for staff and students may simply be motivated by vengeance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. (edit)  I just reread the question.  I would just stick to what you are doing and say the principle approved it.  It is not clear who "they" is in the context of the complaints.  If the principal changes his mind and gives you a direct order, then comply with that new order. But don't get dragged into debate with colleagues or kids.
2. My advice is to consider this an issue between you and the administration.  The issue of the students is not the key concern.  Yes, I get that the admins refer to this and I get the kids chip in on it, but at the end of the day, students get used to what happens.  I would just not engage them in debate.  It's not up to them.
3. As far as the admin:  Either you just do what they tell you or you get them to allow you to do things how you prefer. It is hard for me to understand how much of a big deal it is or not.  Or how important you are to them.  My gut would be just to follow policy.  But it may be possible that they can/will bend.
4. I get that you are used to this tool and it makes you more efficient, but perhaps there is some workaround.  Transferring things to a cheap used laptop (is that allowed)?  Or just some efficient paper based system--I'm old enough so that I remember teachers using those little attendance/grading books that look like a ledger.  Perhaps you are using a lot of worksheets or the like, but could convert to using the textbook more or the chalkboard (for drill)?  Also, transparencies and overhead projection can be very easy (faster than writing chalk and erasing).  And you can save the content (use permanent ink, use those 3 hole sheet protector sleeve things to put the acetate sheets in).  Donno, and not saying it will be as nice as your system on your tablet.  But think about it and how important the job is.  [And at the end of the day, don't stress too much.  Life goes on and every job has its little BS.  How do the other teaches get their classes done?  Why can't you do what they do?]

Comment: A laptop is a bigger problem in class. It seems that the person responsible in dealing with students' complaints is weak. I will try to stick with the tablet and see what will happen in the following days. It's a small school and they constantly change their rules, the rules that they (administration) don't follow.